# How to isolate result from parent string?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Do you have ideas how could I isolate result from the following task..

I have a column which contrains the following value:

```
col_1
10001A
10001A10002A
10001A10002A10003A
10004A
10004A10005B
10006A
10007A
10007A10008A
```

I should select only the rows which don't have offsprings -

```
col_1
10001A10002A10003A
10004A10005B
10006A
10007A10008A
```

Comment: This is a really bad way to store hierarchical information.

Answer (score 2):

You need a like condition to find those rows:

```
select *
from the_table t1 
where not exists (select *
                  from the_table t2
                  where t2.col_1 like t1.col_1||'%'
                   and t1.col_1 <> t2.col_2);
```

Online example: https://rextester.com/GVGVV77242

Comment: Thank you so much! Could I ask something - what does ||'%' do in row "where t2.col_1 like t1.col_1||'%"?

Comment: @SammyMerk: `||` is the string concatenation operator in SQL and it appends a wildcard for the `LIKE` operator to the value that is compared.